# How can I extend a semi-circle smoothly?

Tags: svg

I am trying to draw a semi-circle with the two ends extended, like a horse-shoe on its side.

However I cannot get a smooth join at the ends of the semi-circle.  I have tried two ways – clipping a circle and drawing an arc – and neither works, though for different reasons.  My results are consistent across Chrome, Firefox, and Safari (on macOS).

This seems like a straightforward thing for SVG to do.  How can I get both ways (or one) to work?

#### Clipping a circle

The problem here is that the inside of the semi-circle has too big a radius and doesn't join the rectangles smoothly.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 40" width="500px" height="400px" stroke="black" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect x="0" y="0" height="10" width="30"></rect>
  <rect x="0" y="30" height="10" width="30"></rect>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="foo">
      <rect x="30" y="0" width="20" height="40"></rect>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="30" cy="20" r="15" stroke-width="10" clip-path="url(#foo)" fill="none"></circle>
</svg>
```

#### Arc

The problem here is that the top, right, and bottom (and left?) edges of the SVG are cut-off.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 40" width="500px" height="400px" stroke="black" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect x="0" y="0" height="10" width="30"></rect>
  <rect x="0" y="30" height="10" width="30"></rect>
  <path d="
    M 30,10         
    A 10,10 0 1 1 30,30
    M 30,40
    A 20,20 0 1 0 30,0
  "></path>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow for the line-thickness by inreasing your view area accordingly:

```html
<svg viewBox="-5 -5 60 50" width="500px" height="400px" stroke="black" fill="grey" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect x="0" y="0" height="10" width="30"></rect>
  <rect x="0" y="30" height="10" width="30"></rect>
  <path d="
    M 30,10
    A 10,10 0 1 1 30,30
    M 30,40
    A 20,20 0 1 0 30,0
  "></path>
</svg>
```

With your original definition of your `viewBox="0 0 50 40"` the bordering lines of your rectangles and your arc (with a default line thickness of `1`) were clipped by the viewbox. The increased size of `viewBox="-5 -5 60 50"` allows for more space. To hilight the problem I used `grey` as a "global" filling colour in my example. This makes the `stroke` lines in black visible.

Alternatively you can set your `stroke-width` for all elements to `0` (or, even simpler, set `stroke:none`) and then everything will fit within your original `viewBox="0 0 50 40"`:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 40" width="500px" height="400px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g style="stroke:none; fill:black">
  <rect x="0" y="0" height="10" width="30"/>
  <rect x="0" y="30" height="10" width="30"/>
  <path d="
    M 30,10
    A 10,10 0 1 1 30,30
    M 30,40
    A 20,20 0 1 0 30,0
  "/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Or, a third variant, using a single `path` element with a line-thickness of `10`:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 40" width="500px" height="400px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path style="stroke:black;stroke-width:10; fill:none" d="M 0,5 30,5 A 15,15 0 0 1 30,35 L 0,35"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for this outstanding answer!  It all makes perfect sense now.  I appreciate it.